# Shrink Div as Screen Size gets Larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several images created, I need to change their width and height as my screen size gets larger or smaller. I need the images to **shrink** as my screen size **increases**. I originally thought about vw and vh, but I cannot manipulate my images to what I need. Any thoughts?

If this is not possible in CSS, would it be possible in html, javascript or jquery?

Comment: A simple google search would have let you to enough results to figure it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Have you tried using media queries to do this? Seems straight forward depending on the width of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/7x8st635/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i truly understand you shrink when increase page you can test this:

```
.img{
    width: calc(200px - 10vw); /*for example */
}
```

And it is better using `min-width, min-height` to avoid unwanted sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your **HEAD**  Tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and for the size of your image try to use `width:100%` in your css and add this  line `height:100%` in your **html** and **body** in css

and you can see a demo here :

[Scaled header and nav-bar](http://codepen.io/rafongol/pen/NpWXBY/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with CSS. You can use media queries in CSS to change the size of the image as it reaches a particular width breakpoint. eg:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .image {
        width:500px;
        height:500px
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .image {
        width:300px;
        height:300px
    }
}
```

What will happen with the above code is that when your screen size is less than 768px, then your image height and width will be 500px each. And when your screen size is less than 320px, then your image height and width will be 300px each.

For more information you can search about "responsive web design" and "media queries".

If you are using bootstrap, then you just have to give "img-responsive" class to your image, and the job is done.

NOTE: you have to add following in your head section of your page:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I hope this helps